# Tagged PDF NOT able to Read HyphenSpan

Tags: pdf, pdfbox, tagged-pdf

Here I have 2 PDF's where we have Hyphen used in the text of the document at the end of the fourth line of the PDF (see below.)

Where we have a text `de - (cember)` in the next line.

In both the PDF's the '-' has been tagged as Hyphen Span. But while using the JAWS to read both the files, in one file it is reading as `December` and another PDF file as `De dash cember`.

[PDF that reads december as de -(dash) cember](https://acrobat.adobe.com/link/review?uri=urn:aaid:scds:US:5b4ec0cb-38c2-33c0-8174-50ec0722f0c2)

[PDF that which reads december as december](https://acrobat.adobe.com/link/review?uri=urn:aaid:scds:US:0c04c95e-69e4-378b-be18-4b2da1cdfa59)

I wish to confirm if it is related to a content stream.

Comment: The most obvious differences are that in your second file (1) the structure element dictionary of that hyphen has an **ActualText** entry with a dash as value and (2) the structure type of that structure element, **HyphenSpan**, in the **RoleMap** is mapped to **Span**. In your first file there is neither an **ActualText** entry for it not a role mapping for its type. You may want to look into these differences.

Comment: Hi some how i was able to add the ROLEMAP into the Structure tree root  which maps the HphenSpan to Span link of pdf :- https://acrobat.adobe.com/link/review?uri=urn:aaid:scds:US:6afbd4cc-535b-3562-b107-13791c9c5a95 , still Jaws is reading it as "de dash cember" , and not sure how to find the "the structure element dictionary of that hyphen has an ActualText entry with a dash as value " this one , any inputs will be helpfull , Thanks in advance (:

Comment: why the pdfbox label?

Comment: I am using pdfbox to tag the page content hence we have used PDFBOX , and the use case belongs to tagging..

Comment: Hi @mkl i was able to figure out the Actual Text and Role Map , i have added  both to the PDF below . Still when i check in jaws it is reading as "De dash cember". https://acrobat.adobe.com/link/review?uri=urn:aaid:scds:US:10286014-30d9-36a7-92b5-f47bfa3e9835 , any input will be helpfull , Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To read this text `de - (cember)` as december, we need to make hyphen `-` as soft hyphen by setting the actual text as the Unicode of the soft hyphen `\u00AD`.

`structureElement.setActualText("\u00AD");`